# Asymptotic time complexity, Big oh and Theta analysis. Is this a trick question though

Tags: recursion, big-o, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory, traversal

Here's the question:

Consider the following sorting algorithm: I. Insert the given input A[1], A[2], ..., A[n] into a binary search tree T in the given order, starting from an empty tree; II. Do an inorder traversal of T to output the elements in non-decreasing order. (a) What is the worst case time for the algorithm? (b) What is the best case time for the algorithm?

My answer:

I created a BST in `t(n) = 2(n/2) + n` as we have to go through each individual element, I also then printed out the BST inorder in `t(n) = 2(n/2) + n` as again we have to go through each element. I then added the time complexities together ending with, `t(n) = 4(n/2)+2n`.

According to Master's method, this complies with case 1. Making it `θ(n^2)`. If it is `θ(n^2)`, this answers both a and b of the question. I don't see how there could be a better performance, or in that case a worse performance.

Is this a trick question?

Comment: Shouldn't insertion of one element into a balanced binary tree be `log_2 n`. And shouldn't a binary tree created by inserting a sorted sequence result in a tree that looks like a linked list (with inserts always at the end, so O(n) for a single item)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

> You added the RHS of the two equations but not the LHS – it should be `2T(n)`.

Sure, the verbal description of `T(n)` is the "time complexity function", but of *what*? In this case it should the time complexity of *either* the BST creation *or* in-order traversal, not both together.

So the end result is `2T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 2n`. Cancel the 2, and you get `O(n log n)`.

---

**tl;dr answer**:

> But wait, why `n log n` for traversal too? There are only `n` elements, right?

By splitting the problem into two equal halves `T(n/2)`, you have implicitly assumed that the tree is *balanced* after every insertion. For a simple non-self-balancing BST tree implementation, this will not always be the case. If the tree is "tilted" to one side, an insertion could be as much as `O(n)` (i.e. `O(n^2)` construction).

Fortunately, for most commonly used self-balancing tree types, e.g. Red-Black and AVL, insertion is guaranteed to be `O(log n)` or below. Therefore the *correct* recurrence relation for tree construction is `T(n) = T(n - 1) + log n`, which works out to be `O(n log n)` (Stirling's equation).

Nonetheless, traversal for *any* BST, balanced or not, is `O(n)`, since there are only `n` elements. This means that your recurrence relation for traversal is wrong - it should be `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1`, since only `O(1)` work is done for each node.

Comment: That made so much sense. Thank you!